# Django signals not working on usercreation

Tags: python, django

I created a signals supposed to create a profile for each created users in my `signals.py` file but it's not working. I've tried to check if there's an error with the command `python manage.py check`, but that seems not to work as well.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}'s profile "
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
        if created:
                Profle.instance.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from how i installed the users app in the settings.py file in the main project directory.

**i used** :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users',
]
```

**instead of **

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of parameters in your signal handler is wrong, change:

```py
def create_profile(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
```

to:

```py
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
```

Check the [`post_signal` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-save) for further details.