# Django signals not working inspite of putting everything in place

Tags: python, django, django-signals

**My Case**
In my case User is the default django user model and I've created a Profile to add more details to the User model.
**To achieve**
Now what i want is that whenever I create a new User a Profile for that user should automatically get created.
**I've done**
1. I have checked my signals.py file and also imported the signals in apps.py file but still nw Profile is not being created for each new user being created :( 
2. Tried adding 'users.apps.UsersConfig' to my INSTALLED_APPS and it didn't work out as well.
**Code below**
I have provided the code in my signals.py and apps.py file below.
Please ask me if you need some more code
and thanks in advance :)

Here is my signals.py file

```
#This is the signal that will be sent
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

#This is the object which will send the signal
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

#This will receive the signal
from django.dispatch import receiver

#We need this to perform operations on profiles table
from .models import Profile

#This function creates new profile for each user created
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

#This function saves those newly created profiles
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Here is my apps.py file

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

Here are my INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 #Custom Apps
'product',
'shop',
'market',
'pages',
'users',
]
```

Comment: And is `users.apps.UsersConfig` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: As an aside, custom user models are a more modern and less error-prone way of having custom profiles.

Comment: @AKX No it wasn't placed there, I've placed 'users.apps.UsersConfig' in my INSTALLED_APPS and now it gives me this error on restarting the server: "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, d
uplicates: users"

Comment: I've tried using post_save.connect() method and it's working correctly for me.But I still want to find out why it's not working with using the way I was previously doing it.

Comment: @AKX yep you were right and thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using 'users' in INSTALLED_APPS instead of 'users.apps.UsersConfig'.
My new working INSTALLED_APPS looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
#Custom Apps
'product',
'shop',
'market',
'pages',
'users.apps.UsersConfig', #Signals wont work if you just write 'users'
]
```

Or just refer to a similar question :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59028716/11687381

Comment: As an aside, you can also add `default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'` in `users/__init__.py`, and it'll redirect `'users',` to point to the config.

Comment: Yup got it , that was helpful.